# how to hide the Threshold from Legend using Amcharts 3?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, amcharts, amcharts4

hey i am using Amcharts 3, i need to hide the threshold from the legend,
this is the threshold that i am using graph Highs and graph lows what i need to add to hide it from legend

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIDab.png)

```
                   const graphHighs = {
                        pk: series.pk,
                        lineColor: series.seriesMetaData.colorHex,
                        lineThickness: series.graph.thickness,
                        valueField: `${series.pk.uuid}${series.seriesMetaData.reportType}-highs`,
                        valueAxis: series.seriesMetaData.unitOfMeasurement,
                        lineAlpha: series.graph.opacity,
                        dashLength: 14,
                        type: 'line',
                        hiddenInLegend: true,
                    }

                    const graphLows = {
                        pk: series.pk,
                        lineColor: series.seriesMetaData.colorHex,
                        valueAxis: series.seriesMetaData.unitOfMeasurement,
                        lineThickness: series.graph.thickness,
                        valueField: `${series.pk.uuid}${series.seriesMetaData.reportType}-lows`,
                        lineAlpha: series.graph.opacity,
                        dashLength: 14,
                        type: 'line',
                        hiddenInLegend: true,
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add visibleInLegend = false like this:

```
const graphHighs = {
                        pk: series.pk,
                        lineColor: series.seriesMetaData.colorHex,
                        lineThickness: series.graph.thickness,
                        valueField: `${series.pk.uuid}${series.seriesMetaData.reportType}-highs`,
                        valueAxis: series.seriesMetaData.unitOfMeasurement,
                        lineAlpha: series.graph.opacity,
                        dashLength: 14,
                        type: 'line',
                        visibleInLegend: false,
                    }

                    const graphLows = {
                        pk: series.pk,
                        lineColor: series.seriesMetaData.colorHex,
                        valueAxis: series.seriesMetaData.unitOfMeasurement,
                        lineThickness: series.graph.thickness,
                        valueField: `${series.pk.uuid}${series.seriesMetaData.reportType}-lows`,
                        lineAlpha: series.graph.opacity,
                        dashLength: 14,
                        type: 'line',
                        visibleInLegend: false,
                    }
```